# Would there be any benefits, or repercussions, of exposing my population to a constant rain of blood?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm in the progress of setting up plans for a whole new fortress, and I'd like to dedicate this to the splendour of the blood god himself. In other words, I need to spray my dwarves in large amounts of ☼blood☼.

**What would the <s>repercussions</s> benefits be?**

The wiki list of thoughts doesn't contain anything pertaining to blood showers as far as I've found (`<C-f> blood` finds a single entry)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are unlikely to be many benefits, beyond the bragging rights. There would however be several minor drawbacks.

- While the blood itself doesn't cause bad thoughts (unless it's from an evil biome rain, in which case it's just as likely to melt your dwarves' torsos off.), the remaining body parts from whatever you got the blood out of can rot and cause miasma which does cause bad thoughts.
- Unless you tell them not to your dwarves will attempt to [clean](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Cleaning) the blood up. This could slow down your fortress, but cleaning is a low priority task.
- [Contaminants](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Contaminant) are tracked however, and making too many of them can impact your [framerate](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Maximizing_framerate).
- Dealing with the useless non-blood portions of whatever you got the blood from can also impact both framerate and fortress efficiency by being more items, and generating refuse hauling jobs respectively.
- There are some feasibility concerns, but that is what !!Science!! is for.

Comment: The meeting hall's surrounded by a shallow moat, so the contaminants are contained. Also, since I'm in a **terrifying** biome, the corpses will just not die (and I'm kind of curious if whether living corpses generate miasma or not).

Comment: As for the feasibility concerns, it's totally doable. I've so far built a shaft 12 tiles long, with a grate at the end, and the subjects did a lovely splash when they reached it.